# Powershell parameter reliant on another parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters

If I have  a PowerShell parameter like below:

```
 $foo = "bar"
```

And I have a user input variable which will end up being:

```
$userInput = "foo"
```

How would I then get the vale of `$foo` using the value of `$userInput`?

If I create a parameter:

```
$this = "$" +  $userInput
```

That would make `$this` equal to the string '$foo' and not the value of `$foo`.

Is there a way I can get it to treat it as a variable and not a literal string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Get-Variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx), that is

```
$otherVar = Get-Variable $userInput
```